# dismiss progress dialog in asyntask

Tags: android, progressdialog

**I have search box in my page,I added onTextChangeListener() too. When I am add/removing letters/characters from search box ,every time I am calling same asyntask.Suppose 3 times called then 3 times progress dialog instances getting created and need to dismissed.Here progress dialog is not getting dismissed.**

```
search.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                searchresult = search.getText().toString();

                if (count == 0) {
                    pageCount = 1;
                    productsList.clear();
                    mCount = 0;
                    if (isTextWatcherVisible) {
//                        GetProductsTask();
                        new GetProductsTask().execute();
                    }
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            }
        });   
class GetProductsTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    final String pcid = Preferences.getString(Preferences.PrefType.enum_company_id, getActivity());

    String url1 = getContext().getString(R.string.url) + "products?company_id=" + pcid + "&page=" + pageCount;

    public GetProductsTask() {
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        progressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    }
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
//                progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
//                progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
//                progressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
//                progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
      // somthig here
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        ProductslistAdapter adapter = new ProductslistAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.vendor_products_item, productsList, searchresult);

        list.setAdapter(adapter);
        int count = pageCount - 1;
        list.setSelection(count * 24);
        if (progressDialog.isShowing())
            progressDialog.dismiss();

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// here your everytime your creating the dialog box, loosing previous reference. And "progressDialog " is not local to class "GetProductsTask".     
   progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
    progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    progressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
    progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
```

solution :

```
class GetProductsTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
//make it local to class
ProgressDialog progressDialog;
```

Comment: I did it my friend.

Answer (score 2):

just create one method like:

```
private static ProgressDialog progressDialog;

public static void showProgressDialog(Context context) {

        if (progressDialog == null) {
            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            progressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
            progressDialog.show();
        }

}
```

call **showProgressDialog** method into **onPreExecute()**.

To dismiss dialog:

```
if(progressdailog.isShowing()){
    progressdialog.dismiss();
}
```

Comment: It would be nice to explain why this code will work and what's the SO problem with his code.

Comment: @danypata **if (progressDialog == null)** here we are checking that if there is any instance running for progress dialog or not. If dialog is already running then no new dialog instance created. In this way only one instance will run at a time.

Answer (score 1):

This cause of this issue is:

```
new GetProductsTask().execute();
```

This statement is creating new task each time you type character. So you need to create new task after cancelling current.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
   GetProductsTask getProductsTask = null;
   ProgressDialog ProgressDialog = null;


  public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        //Replace this: new GetProductsTask().execute();
        if(getProductsTask != null) {
            getProductsTask.cancel();
            getProductsTask = null;
        }

        getProductsTask = new GetProductsTask();
        getProductsTask.execute();
   }

   class GetProductsTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        //Add new method inside it
        public void onCancelled (Result result) {
            //Got call when task is cancelled
        }
   }
}
```

Hope it works you for.

Comment: He cannot cancel the dialog once created if you can see `setCancelable(false);` so he has to wait for the result and after which it will be dismissed.

Comment: `setCancelable(false);` means Sets whether this dialog is cancelable with the BACK key. Please visit here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#setCancelable(boolean)

Answer (score 0):

In your `AsynchTask` `onPreExecute()` method first check for progress Dialog if it is null then initialize and show it.

```
protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
         if (progressDialog == null) {
            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            progressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
            progressDialog.show();
        }
    }
```

And in `onPostExecute()` method just dismiss it.

```
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        // Your other code goes here
        if(progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                progressDialog = null;
         }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update AsyncTask as below:**

```
class GetProductsTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    final String pcid = Preferences.getString(Preferences.PrefType.enum_company_id, getActivity());
    String url1 = getContext().getString(R.string.url) + "products?company_id=" + pcid + "&page=" + pageCount;

    ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    public GetProductsTask() {
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
    }

    protected void onPreExecute() {

        progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        progressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // somthig here

        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

        ProductslistAdapter adapter = new ProductslistAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.vendor_products_item, productsList, searchresult);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);

        int count = pageCount - 1;
        list.setSelection(count * 24);

        if (progressDialog.isShowing())
            progressDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this where you want to dismiss dialog.

```
ProgressDialog pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
pDialog.dismiss();
```